# Bash shell copy files on the hidden directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, copy

Need help with Unix script.

how do you use /bin/cp to copy files from /somepath/somedir/somewhere/.temp_folder to /somepath/somedir/somewhere/

my line

```
/bin/cp -r somepath/somedir/somewhere/.[!.]* somepath/somedir/somewhere/
```

the directory **.temp_folder** Is copied but I want to copy only files

tia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more glob after directory:

```
cp -r somepath/somedir/somewhere/.[!.]*/* somepath/somedir/somewhere/
```

`somepath/somedir/somewhere/.[!.]*/*` will match files and directories inside `.temp_folder`